# Set up autocomplete mode in emacs to work well with C structs

Tags: c, emacs, autocomplete, struct, structure

I am tying to get emacs to list only valid autocomplete options when working with structs. 
For example, consider the following struct:

```
typedef struct      
{  
    int length, width, area;  
} SquareType;

SquareType *square;
```

When I type `square->`, I would like a menu to pop up showing **only** the valid struct members.

Currently, with the following in my .emacs file, a popup menu shows up only if I type another character after `->`. Also, the current menu lists completion options that are not valid members of my struct.

```
(require 'yasnippet)  
(require 'auto-complete-config)  
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")  
(ac-config-default)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you need is CEDET/semantic.
It's already built-in the new Emacs versions.
It does code analysis, so it will show you the valid members of your struct.

1. enable semantic with `(semantic-mode 1)`
2. call `semantic-analyze-possible-completions` to show the completions
3. I tested this with `emacs -q` for Emacs 24.3.1 - it works.

There's also `semantic-ia-complete-symbol` and a lot of other functions
that you might be interested in.

Although `auto-complete-mode` does feature `ac-source-semantic`,
and it kind of does what you ask, I wouldn't recommend it.
One problem with it is that `ac-source-semantic` would be just one of many
sources, so you'd get more candidates than 3 for your case.
Second problem is that semantic is a bit slow, especially when `auto-complete`
keeps polling it after each key stroke, so you'll really feel a drop
in responsiveness.

I keep just the basics for my `ac-sources`:

```
(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)
```

And when I require semantic completion, I just call it with <kbd>C-o</kbd>
to get only valid candidates.

I also maintain a repository with my additions to semantic at
[github](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args)
If you'd like to try it, the completion function is called `moo-complete`.
Just bind it to <kbd>C-o</kbd> and give it a try.

Comment: ac works fine with semantic - it simply make sense to disable automatic invocation of ac-mode (look onto corresponding section in my article: http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html)... External name completions are also now recommended way to complete names in CEDET

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point I was trying to make.
I think that the whole point of auto-complete is that it's automatic, so I keep it that way.
And I only resort to semantic completion if auto-complete gets it wrong, or can't guess.